# erro getting SSL from sslforfee.com - > acme-challenge

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

NodeJs Code :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();



app .get('/.well-known/acme-challenge/:name', function(req, res) { 
  var options = {
    root: __dirname + '/public/',
    dotfiles: 'deny',
    headers: {
        'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
        'x-sent': true
    }
  };

  var fileName = req.params.name;
  res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Sent:', fileName);
    }
   res.redirect("/");
  });;})


var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpServer.listen(80);
httpsServer.listen(443);
```

Trying to get a free sll certificate from sslforfree.com

error i get when trying acme-challenge :

```
Domain "fittflotta.com" challenge3 failed. Response from "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/tYj3dJCC9HorZkazj1dMNrepfgA43IAbeJ8gaC5vBV0/4174825072" was: 

Error: Invalid response from http://fittflotta.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/U3ezyFEBkPOS3q4dvUFkbJAew7ctzUrgJZgb4sIs6H4: " <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> <html> <head> <title>fit"

Full Error: { "type": "http-01", "status": "invalid", "error": { "type": "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized", "detail": "Invalid response from http://fittflotta.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/U3ezyFEBkPOS3q4dvUFkbJAew7ctzUrgJZgb4sIs6H4: \"\r\n\u003c!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\"\r\n \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\"\u003e\r\n\u003chtml\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003chead\u003e\r\n \u003ctitle\u003efit\"", "status": 403 }, "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/tYj3dJCC9HorZkazj1dMNrepfgA43IAbeJ8gaC5vBV0/4174825072", "token": "U3ezyFEBkPOS3q4dvUFkbJAew7ctzUrgJZgb4sIs6H4", "validationRecord": [ { "url": "http://fittflotta.com/eVkTh/.well-known/acme-challenge/U3ezyFEBkPOS3q4dvUFkbJAew7ctzUrgJZgb4sIs6H4", "hostname": "fittflotta.com", "port": "80", "addressesResolved": [ "50.63.202.23" ], "addressUsed": "50.63.202.23" }, { "url": "http://fittflotta.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/U3ezyFEBkPOS3q4dvUFkbJAew7ctzUrgJZgb4sIs6H4", "hostname": "fittflotta.com", "port": "80", "addressesResolved": [ "50.63.202.23" ], "addressUsed": "50.63.202.23" }, { "url": "http://fittflotta.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/U3ezyFEBkPOS3q4dvUFkbJAew7ctzUrgJZgb4sIs6H4", "hostname": "fittflotta.com", "port": "80", "addressesResolved": [ "50.63.202.23" ], "addressUsed": "50.63.202.23" } ] }
```

how can fix this if there is anything i need to provide i am willing to :)
Thank you?

Comment: You are sending a document on that `URL`. Leave it.

Comment: trying to found out how to, but what should i send?

Comment: You want to make sure, that — nothing — is sent by you. `Letsencrypt` sends it by itself.

Comment: if i use app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); ,same thing , i am really confused,

Comment: You want to get rid of the whole block `app .get('/.well-known/acme-challenge/:name'...`. Letsencrypt got its own server.

Comment: i dont get, could you please explain it bit more?

Comment: If you send something, it does — not — work. Leave it be.

Comment: Perhaps it is also your `redirect` to `/`.